# Android, Calling a method from intentService on a particular date and time

Tags: android, intentservice, android-alarms, android-intentservice

I have a IntentService, Suppose I launch it today 27/12/2015.

I want it to wait for a specific date and time i.e 05/01/2016 08:54 AM, On this date and time i want it call a method to do something.

Comment: well i did a bit of study on alarmManager i don't think i can achieve my goal with it, so now if i some how can make an algorithm that can find the total miliseconds between two dates and time, i can put that service to slee, well im a newbie here don't know much about android.

Comment: try some android tutorials to get you used to the basics, then look at the date/time API documentation, that should get you started.

Comment: Time api is deprecated now,                                                                                         Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("d:M:yy");
        SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:m");
        SimpleDateFormat amPm = new SimpleDateFormat("a");

        Time = time.format(c.getTime());
        Date = date.format(c.getTime());
        AmPm = amPm.format(c.getTime()); This is how i'm getting time date but the problem is how do i invoke it on a particular date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO i finally did it, posting the answer here for anyone who needs it, it is not the best way but its a way to get the job done the only solution i can came up with and stop voting down my question.

```
String userTime = textFiled1.getText().toString();
String userDate = textField2.getText().toString();

for(;;){
   Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yy");
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");

    Time = time.format(c.getTime());
    Date = date.format(c.getTime());


   if(userDate.equals(Date)){
       if(userTime.equals(Time)){
            // your code;

            break;
       }
   }
}
```